# Rails: Outputting translation in link_to() method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a link_to method that requires the body argument to be populated by translated material.

For example:
`link_to('translated material', '/dashboard')`

I currently have it set up so in my en.yml (for example) has:

```
en:
  dashboard: 'Dashboard'
```

and in a typical situation where I need translation I would just do, for example, this: `<%= t :dashboard %>`

This works great. However, how do I place that into the link_to() method like so:

`link_to(*insert :dashboard translated text here*, '/dashboard')`

I'm sure it's simple formatting, still learning all the nuances of ROR!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put everything together:

```
link_to(t('dashboard'), dashboard_path)
```

btw. it is preferred to use the named routes. Do not use strings as urls.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure of the formatting. Cleared some fundamental syntax knowledge up for me